# uninitialized constant UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise and therefore do not need a **users controller**.However, i also need nested routes and my config.routes looks like this;

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users

  resources :users do 
    resources :personal_accounts,path: "user_account", only: [:show] do
      resources :deposits, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index]
      resources :withdraws, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index]
    end
    resources :businesses do
      resources :business_accounts, path: "business_account", only: [:show] do 
        resources :business_withdraws, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index]
        resources :business_deposits, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index]
      end
    end
  end
```

How can i go past this error while also maintaining my nested routes.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have three levels of nested routes there, which is normally considered to be undesirable: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

This bit `resources :users do` will create all the named routes for the users controller, which I suspect is where your error comes from. Why do you need this? Better perhaps to specify the routes without it?

```
resources :personal_accounts,path: "user_account", only: [:show] do
  resources :deposits, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index]
  resources :withdraws, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index]
end
```